# Basemap error: module object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to learn how to use basemap in python. I used the following site for learning http://www.datadependence.com/2016/06/creating-map-visualisations-in-python/.
but when I typed the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm
import basemap
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))
m=basemap(resolution='c',projection='merc',lat_0=54.5,lon_0=-4.36,llcrnrlon=-6.,llcrnrlat=49.5,urcrnrlon=2.,urcrnrlat=55.2)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#46bcec')
m.fillcontinents(color='#f2f2f2',lake_color='#46bcec')
m.drawcoastlines()
```

I get an error as `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. Why is the reason for this?

Comment: please don't tag your title - that's what the actual tags are for

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the example code. You have to write:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
m=Basemap(resolution='c',projection='merc',lat_0=54.5,lon_0=-4.36,llcrnrlon=-6.,llcrnrlat=49.5,urcrnrlon=2.,urcrnrlat=55.2)
```

`Basemap` have to be start from capital letter. It is very important for Python. Python is case sensitivity language.