# basemap TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib, module, matplotlib-basemap

This question is **not** a duplicate of [Basemap error: module object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685170/basemap-error-module-object-is-not-callable)

The solution to that is to ensure the `b` in `Basemap` is capitalised. I am getting this problem regardless of that. Here's my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
Basemap()
```

And here's the error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This is a simple way of recreating the error. In reality, I am mimicking code found in [pysplit](https://github.com/mscross/pysplit), in the [mapdesigner.py](https://github.com/mscross/pysplit/blob/master/pysplit/mapdesigner.py#L309) file on line 309.

If anyone knows a way to fix this issue please let me know.

edit:

Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    Basemap()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

From an actual python file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\stuff\test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    Basemap()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Show the exact, complete error message, including full stack trace.

Comment: It seems like `mpl_toolkits.basemap` has been [deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/index.html#deprecation-notice).

Comment: Also, possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import). Hopefully it helps you out. 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python basemap module impossible to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import)

Comment: The question does not provide enough information to know why this simply command fails for you. What happens if in a command line you do `python -c "from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap; Basemap()"`? Also, do you have a file called `Basemap.py` in your folder that would shaddow the real basemap module?

Comment: @user2357112 I edited to included the full error traceback. That's why I didn't include it in the error, because it's not very useful

Comment: @FelipeFaria That doesn't help me, the package I'm using uses it regardless of whether it's deprecated or not

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yeh that was my first thought about the shadowing, and no I don't have another file named `Basemap.py`. Running `python -c "from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap; Basemap()"` produces exactly the same error.

Comment: @FelipeFaria I don't have any problem importing `Basemap`, only using it. So I don't get the same error as in the duplicate you included

Comment: @Recessive Understood. Perhaps the post can help anyhow -- would recommend browsing through its answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I used to install `Basemap` (whichever it is, I can't remember because it was months ago) didn't install Basemap, instead it placed `Basemap` with a `setup.py` file ready to be installed in my `site-packages`.

This `setup.py` of course doesn't work, but that's a separate issue. At least I know why this isn't working.

Comment: Have a look here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53292945/10640534) for how to install Basemap on Ubuntu. :)